# Avoid conversion of compound types to text

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

My compound types when returned from `PLPGSQL` function are converted to text:

```
dev=# select * from app.user_query_test(3);
   user_record   |   udata_record    
-----------------+-------------------
 (3,875227490,t) | (3,3,"Bob Smith")
(1 row)

dev=#
```

I don't want this, I want to receive them on the client side as nested object of data, like this:

```
{
   "user_record": {
         "user_id": 3,
         "identity_id": 875227490,
         "utype": t
    },
    "udata_record": {
          "udata_id": 3,
          "user_id": 3,
          "full_name": "Bob Smith"
    }
}
```

But, I also don't want `JSON`, because decoding/encoding to `JSON` format will require processing time and will affect the performance of my App. So how do I achieve this? I mean how do I put the data on the Client in the exact structure as it is returned by `PLPGSQL` function without any decoding/encoding process?

My source files are:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS app.user_reply_t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE app.user_reply_t AS (
    user_id         integer,
    identity_id     integer,
    utype           boolean
);
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS app.udata_reply_t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE app.udata_reply_t AS (
    udata_id        integer,
    user_id         integer,
    full_name       varchar(64)
);
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS app.user_info_t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE app.user_info_t AS (
    user_record     app.user_reply_t,
    udata_record    app.udata_reply_t
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.user_query_test(p_user_id integer) 
RETURNS app.user_info_t AS 
$$
DECLARE
    rec             app.user_info_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT user_id,identity_id,utype FROM "comp-158572724".users WHERE user_id=p_user_id INTO rec.user_record;
    SELECT udata_id,user_id,full_name FROM "comp-158572724".udata WHERE user_id=p_user_id INTO rec.udata_record;
    RETURN rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Tested with Node.js:

```
 src $ node usertest.js 
result={ command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  rows: 
   [ { user_record: '(3,875227490,t)',
       udata_record: '(3,3,"Bob Smith")' } ],
  fields: 
   [ { name: 'user_record', dataTypeID: 19862 },
     { name: 'udata_record', dataTypeID: 19865 } ] }
^C
 src $
```

Source of Client code:

```
src $ cat usertest.js 
const util = require('util');
pg = require('pg').native
var Pool = pg.Pool
var Client = pg.Client
var pool=new Pool({
    user:     'dev_user',
    password: 'dev',
    host:     'localhost',
    database: 'dev'
});

pool.query('select * from app.user_query_test(3)',function(err, result) {
        console.log('result=' + util.inspect(result));
    }
);
function wait() {
    console.log('wating...');
    setTimeout(wait,3000);
}
setTimeout(wait,3000);
 src $
```

Comment: @Abelisto, but that would be without preserving the data structure, just an array of fields. What I want is to get it as user_record.fieldX on the client side.

Comment: Not sure that it is possible without decoding/encoding the result. However add `node.js` tag to the question.

Comment: @Abelisto, but this is not Node.js related , if I would using Java or PHP, I would need the same thing. Tell me how to do the same in PHP and I will accept the answer

Comment: Nope. PostgreSQL provides the pairs "field type"-"field value". And client software could (or could not) to convert the value to its specific data type based on "field type". So my suggestion is: use JSON because it is native for JS.

Comment: @Abelisto, too bad. I thought it was possible to use native Postgres protocol to deliver user-defined types to the client side without additional decoding/encoding process.

Comment: You can check what is possible in the basic level in the [API documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO). For example: `char *PQgetvalue(const PGresult *res, int row_number, int column_number);` - as you can see the function returns just `char*` for each field value.